# Installation issue with AWS for Ada

Tags: installation, ada

I installed Ada and AWS on a Macbook for the first time tonight.

Everything seemed successful with the installation, but I'm getting the feeling that AWS didn't install to the right directory.

GNAT is in /usr/local/gnat.

The AWS makefile.conf said,

```
AWS will be installed under $(prefix). Update this variable to point to
the install directory. By default, it is set to the current GNAT root
directory to have AWS project files automatically available.
```

So I didn't change the target.

But when I try to compile hello_world from anywhere on the system except the AWS demos folder, I get this error:

```
~/projects/ada:gnatmake hello.adb
gcc -c hello.adb
hello.adb:1:06: file "aws.ads" not found
hello.adb:2:06: file "aws.ads" not found
hello.adb:3:06: file "aws.ads" not found
hello.adb:4:06: file "aws.ads" not found
gnatmake: "hello.adb" compilation error
```

How can I make sure AWS was installed properly, or move it if it wasn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer (well, more of a hint to those in the know) lies in the words "to have AWS project files automatically available".

In the GNAT context, "project file" means a file of type `.gpr` which tells the builder (`gnatmake` or `gprbuild`) where to find the source files, how to compile them, and where to find any libraries that "this" project depends on.

Create `hello.gpr`:

```
with "aws";
project Hello is
   for Main use ("hello.adb");
end Hello;
```

(which is *very* minimal) then

```
with AWS;
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("AWS version is " & AWS.Version);
end Hello;
```

compiled with

```
gprbuild -P hello.gpr
```

outputs

```
AWS version is 2.10.0w
```

There is on-line information on [gprbuild](http://www.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html) and [gnatmake](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/) (`gnatmake` has been superseded by `gprbuild`); there is probably information in your installed GNAT at (subdirectories of) `${prefix}/share/doc`.