# Ada Web Server, cannot make simple hello world

Tags: ada

So we downloaded Ada Web Server, GNAT Studio, and put them in appropriate directories. We are not sure what is wrong, we have tried multiple tutorials. Specifically this one would not work [Installation issue with AWS for Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063468/installation-issue-with-aws-for-ada)

We could not compile `gnatmake -P hello.gpr`
When that is run it puts out

```
gcc -x -c  ada hello.gpr
hello.gpr:1:06: identifier expected
hello.gpr:2:01: compilation unit expected
```

This is our compilation error message. We have changed the prefix in the makefile.conf from AWS to the right directory, C:\GNAT\2016

Here is the tutorial we mainly tried to use, this site wont let me post our other resources. 
http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-29/

Please let me know what it takes to get a hello_world working! Is there a better guide for windows 10 GNAT/AWS 2016?

Edit:

the zlib.gpr has errors and it is exactly what I downloaded from libre.adacore.com.

```
c:\GNAT\2016\Workspace\aws>gprbuild hello.gpr
zlib.gpr:19:06: unknown project file: "../../.build/projects/aws_config"
zlib.gpr:19:06: imported by "C:\GNAT\2016\Workspace\aws\include\zlib\zlib.gpr"
zlib.gpr:19:06: imported by "C:\GNAT\2016\Workspace\aws\aws.gpr"
zlib.gpr:19:06: imported by "C:\GNAT\2016\Workspace\aws\hello.gpr"
zlib.gpr:41:10: warning: no when others for this case construction
zlib.gpr:41:15: unknown package or project "Aws_Config"
zlib.gpr:41:15: variable "zlib_exists" is not a single string
gprbuild: "hello.gpr" processing failed
```

Comment: What's in the file "hello.gpr"?  It might be a good idea to use `gprbuild` instead of `gnatmake` as a build manager.  Are you sure you actually included the "-P" on the command line?

Comment: I have updated my answer referred to so it recommends `gprbuild`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure you have used

```
gnatmake -p hello.gpr
```

instead of

```
gnatmake -P hello.gpr
```

`-P file` means "use the project file `file`", `-p` means "create any missing directories".

And, as others have said, it’s better to use `gprbuild` rather than `gnatmake` (I’ve updated the answer you referred to).

Comment: This helped! I read the --help file and it makes sense now. However, the zlib.gpr has errors and it is exactly what I downloaded from libre.adacore.com. I included the error in the main question, would you please take a look at it and maybe help me understand why the given AWS files are no good?

Comment: Sorry, I’m on a Mac. I don’t see anything about zlib in my installed AWS, but I don’t have zlib installed, so maybe the build process in win32/build.cmd never built it. BUT, it looks from your updated question that you are building hello.adb within the AWS source distribution; perhaps it’s picking up the wrong version of aws.gpr? Try building outside the AWS distribution?

Comment: I've marked your comment as the answer due your interest in helping us! We never managed to get AWS to work though. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't compile a project file via `gcc`. Gcc expects a source file.
Instead, a `.gpr` file is passed to `gprbuild`, which then takes care of spawning compiler, binder and linker to create executables...